# In vim, how do I choose which window to load a quickfix item?

Tags: vim, window

I routinely have 4 windows, split into a 2x2 grid. When I run a command that populates the quickfix, the first matching location is opened in the current window. But if I choose a QF location that isn't already loaded, it always seems to open in bottom-right-hand window.

Is there a way to make it load in a different window? Specifically, is there a way to make it load in the last window I was in - i.e. the window that "CTRL-w p" would take me to?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take a look at [QFEnter](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=4778) vim plugin. It opens a item in the 'wincmd p' window when hitting enter or double-clicking on the quickfix item.
Actually, it's my plugin :)

Comment: Just downloaded the plugin. Perfect. Simply opens the window in the last focused pane. All I needed, because I generally use 2 vertical panes side-by-side for comparing code.

Answer (score 4):

`set switchbuf+=uselast`

if you want to load the quickfix item into the previously used window.

Comment: This is the better answer since it doesn't require a plugin. :help switchbuf also specifically states that it only affects quickfix and buffer related split commands, which is great because it is a low-impact change.

Comment: Side note, why the +=? Why would you want to append this option instead of just doing set switchbuf=uselast?

Comment: This requires a fairly new version of Vim; it would be newer than 8.1.2269, which is what's in (e.g.) Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. I haven't been able to figure out exactly which release first included it, but the commit is at https://github.com/vim/vim/pull/1652/commits/1e613747bd8930740b609715bfda427d0c8d1613.

Answer (score 2):

From `:help quickfix.txt`:

> In the quickfix window, each line is one error.  The line number is equal to
>   the error number.  You can use ":.cc" to jump to the error under the cursor.
>   Hitting the  key or double-clicking the mouse on a line has the same
>   effect.  The file containing the error is opened **in the window above the
>   quickfix window.**  If there already is a window for that file, it is used
>   instead.  If the buffer in the used window has changed, and the error is in
>   another file, jumping to the error will fail.  You will first have to make
>   sure the window contains a buffer which can be abandoned.

I don't think you'll be able to avoid creating a custom mapping.

Comment: Thanks for the info. I guess I can first switch to the window I want, then use BufExplorer to choose the buffer that quickfix loaded in the window I didn't want.